# Construction of $e^{tx}-a-bx \leq 0$

Tags: analysis, functions

I need help for more sophisticated solution because I am trying very mechanically to find:

For $a,b,t \in \mathbb{R}$

- $e^{tx}-a-bx \leq 0$ on $[x_1, x_2]$
- $e^{tx}-a-bx \geq 0$ on $[0,1]\setminus[x_1,x_2]$.

so where $x_1,x_2$ are roots of convex function $e^{tx}-a-bx$ and $0 < x_1 < x_2 < 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical point of this function is at

$$ f'(x) = te^{tx} -b = 0 $$

or $$ x_0 = \frac{1}{t}\ln\left(\frac{b}{t}\right) $$

This allows you to separate the intervals containing the two roots. Then you apply other numerical methods like the midpoint or Newton's.

---

**Edit:** More details

In order for both roots to be in $[0,1]$, we need the critical point to be in the same same range for this to have any chance of happening (see intermediate value theorem). This places a constraint on the parameter

$$ 0 < \frac{1}{t}\ln\left(\frac{b}{t}\right) < 1 \tag{1} $$

So we have $t > 0$ and $ b < te^t$. Neither can be zero (do you see why?)

Next stop, we know $f \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$. Since we want $f$ to cross the $x$-axis twice, two other necessary conditions need to hold
$$ \lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = +\infty \tag{2} $$

which give $b > 0$, and

$$ f(x_0) = \frac{b}{t} - a - \frac{b}{t}\ln\left(\frac{b}{t}\right) < 0 \tag{3} $$

which gives implies $a > -\frac{b}{t}\ln\left(\frac{b}{et}\right)$

Plus, we also need both endpoints to be non-negative. This gives two more conditions
$$ f(0) = 1-a \ge 0 \tag{4} $$
$$ f(1) = e^t-a-b \ge 0 \tag{5} $$

where an equal sign implies a zero at $0$ and/or $1$. Then $(4)$ gives $a \le 1$ and $(5)$ gives $b \le a - e^t$

If you have all of that, the two roots will satisfy
$$ x_1 \in [0,x_0), \quad x_2 \in (x_0,1]  $$

Comment: Could you solve completely my question to give bounty to you?

Comment: I added more stuff. I wasn't sure if you wanted to numerically solve for the roots given $a,b,t$ (as I originally thought), or you wanted some constraints on the parameters. The question wasn't too clear.

Comment: if I want to solve and find what a,b,t if I know roots $x_1, x_2$ do you have any idea?

Comment: You'll need 3 conditions to find 3 unknowns. 2 roots aren't enough.