# How to solve system with two linear equation and three unknowns

Tags: analysis

Suppose that I know two roots $(x_1,x_2)$ of equation $e^{tx}-a-bx$. But I find difficult how to determine a,b,t.

If I express $a,b$ in terms of $t$ then I come with: $$a=\frac{1}{x_2-x_1}[x_2e^{tx_1}-x_1e^{tx_2}]$$ and

$$b=\frac{1}{x_2-x_1}[e^{tx_1}-e^{tx_2}]$$.

But in this I can't find with any solution.

This is related to my previous question: 
[Construction of $e^{tx}-a-bx \leq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2535834/construction-of-etx-a-bx-leq-0)

Comment: you want to solve the System for what variables?

Comment: you want to solve the System for what variables?

Comment: In fact I want to find all a,b,t - but one way that I was thinking was to express a,b in terms of t but it doesn't work. So, any clever idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you did this but I will still include this part.

You have $e^{x_{1,2}t}-a-bx_{1,2}=0$ so $e^{x_{1}t}-a-bx_{1}-e^{x_{2}t}+a+bx_{2}=e^{x_{1}t}-bx_{1}-e^{x_{2}t}+bx_{2}=0$ find $b$: $b(x_1-x_2)=e^{x_{1}t}-e^{x_{2}t}\implies b=\frac{e^{x_{1}t}-e^{x_{2}t}}{x_1-x_2}$

With that you obtain $$e^{tx_1}-a-x_1\frac{e^{x_{1}t}-e^{x_{2}t}}{x_1-x_2}=e^{tx_2}-a-x_2\frac{e^{x_{1}t}-e^{x_{2}t}}{x_1-x_2}\\\therefore e^{tx_1}- x_1\frac{e^{x_{1}t}-e^{x_{2}t}}{x_1-x_2}=e^{tx_2}-x_2\frac{e^{x_{1}t}-e^{x_{2}t}}{x_1-x_2}\\\implies e^{tx_1}-e^{tx_2}=x_1\frac{e^{x_{1}t}-e^{x_{2}t}}{x_1-x_2}-x_2\frac{e^{x_{1}t}-e^{x_{2}t}}{x_1-x_2}\\\implies e^{tx_1}-e^{tx_2}= e^{tx_1}-e^{tx_2}\\\implies 0=0$$ which means that $t$ is the free variable and $a,b$ are dependent on $t$

Comment: Btw, the last equation is also equal to $a$

Comment: I just tried with numbers and it doesn't work... solution says is for t=0 which is not correct.

Comment: @Melina you will get $0=0$, which means that every value for $t$ is okay, why? Because for all $t$ you can find correspond $a,b$ such that $x_{1,2}$ will be it's roots. This happens because you can't find 3 variables with 2 equations, there will always be a free variable, in this case $t$ that the other 2 will depend on, I add it to the answer